# Question Re: Arian Berdellima's Papers On Odd Perfect Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems

Hi everyone.

I'd like to refer you to two papers by Arian Berdellima on odd perfect numbers:

More Properties About Odd Perfect Numbers

http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/31587/1/MPRA_paper_31587.pdf

Perfect numbers - a lower bound for an odd perfect number

http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/31218/1/MPRA_paper_31218.pdf

I have perused both papers, and the first paper in particular appears to have shown that the Euler prime of an odd perfect number must be at least 13.

Can anybody comment as to the merit(s) of these papers?

Comment: In particular, in Proposition 3.2 from the first paper, am I right in thinking that $\beta \ge 0$ instead of $\beta > 0$?

Comment: There is a meta thread on "Discussing preprints on MO" here: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1059/ 

Comment: @Gerald, thanks!  I will check that one out...

Comment: The rule of thumb is that if a manuscript is typed in MS Word, then it's probably rubbish. ;) 

Comment: This seems inappropriate, voting to close.


Comment: Arnie, I suspect proposition 3.1 does not hold, as q_j could be 1 mod q_i.  Further, I do not see that 2beta + 1 has to divide q_i -1, as it could be a multiple of some factor of q_i -1.  So yes, beta could be 0, and the conclusion does not follow in my view.  I also do not see how the proof can be rescued.
Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear Arnie,

In the first paper, "More properties about the odd perfect numbers", there is a flow in the statement of Little Fermat Theorem. The modular congruences that I have used should also satisfy p=1 (mod q) and  q(i)=1(mod q(j)) in order for the results to be applicable. In the second paper there is no error as it was edited by few professors and also it was the topic of my senior thesis. 
My apologies for the misleading result.

Regards,
Arian Berdellima

Comment: In the proof to your proposition 3.1, you start with "Since sigma(p^alpha) <> 2m^2 and sigma(m^2) <> p^alpha ..." .  Could you expand on that part, as it is unclear to me how you get that from your assumptions in the statement of the proposition.  Gerhard "Also Studies Odd Perfect Numbers" Paseman, 2012.02.01

Comment: In proposition 3.1 I use the result from Pomerance that if n=p^alpha*m^2 is an odd perfect number then 
gcd(sigma(m^2), sigma(p^alpha))<>1,therefore for some prime q(i) which divides m^2 we have that q(i)|sigma(m^2) and q(i)|sigma(p^alpha).
So, (1) 1+q(j)+...+q(j)^(2beta)=0 (mod q(i)) Notice that q(i) and q(j) are both prime factors of m^2. From (1) one obtains 
(2) q(j)^(2beta+1)=1 (mod q(i))
Now if q(j)=1 (mod q(i)) then there is nothing to be found because q(j)^n=1 (mod q(i)), n-positive integer. The other case is when q(j)<>1 (mod q(i)). q(j) cant be a primitive root and the results follow

Comment: In TeX: ...if $n=p^{\alpha}m^2$ is an odd perfect number then $\gcd(\sigma(m^2),\sigma(p^{\alpha}))\ne1$, therefore for some prime $q_i$ which divides $m^2$ we have that $q_i\mid\sigma(m^2)$ and $q_i\mid\sigma(p^{\alpha})$. So, (1) $1+q_j+\cdots+q_j^{2\beta}\equiv0\pmod{q_i}$. Notice that $q_i$ and $q_j$ are both prime factors of $m^2$. From (1) one obtains (2) $q_j^{2\beta+1}\equiv1\pmod{q_i}$. Now if $q_j\equiv1\pmod{q_i}$ then there is nothing to be found because $q_j^n\equiv1\pmod{q_i}$, $n$ a positive integer. The other case is when $q_j\not\equiv1\pmod{q_i}$. Continued...

Comment: (Continuation) $q_j$ can't be a primitive root and the results follow. 

Comment: Thank you Garry for your assistance. I hope the paper makes more sense now. 

Comment: Thanks for the follow-through, Arian.  Appreciate it...


Comment: No problem Arnie. I will rewrite the paper so that it is not misleading any more. Appreciate the fact that you expressed an interest in it.